# getting input parameters from matlab using C++ mex Function

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

```
double learning_rate = 1;
int training_epochs = 1;
int k = 1;

int train_S = 6;
int test_S = 6;
int visible_E = 6;
int hidden_E = 6;

// training data
int train_X[6][6] = {
    {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}
};
```

the above code are the input parameters am giving to my function. but i would like to cast them into a function withing my mexFunction and simply call them.
the matlab side has the following

```
clear *
close all
clc

%% Load the data


X=    [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0; ...
        1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0; ...
        1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0; ...
        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0; ...
        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0; ...
        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0];

%% Define Parameters

numHiddenUnits = 6;
numIterations = 1000;
kCD = 1;

%% Compute the RBM

x = RBM(X, numHiddenUnits, numIterations, kCD);
```

Comment: You can find an example of this in [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/). Look for svm_model_matlab.h and svm_model_matlab.c.

Answer (score 0):

Scalar input parameters are fairly simple.  Matrix inputs are little trickier because they use old-school Fortran column major order, you may need to transpose the data before you send it to your function.  Here's kind of an example, you'll have to fill in the blanks:

```
/*=========================================================
 * Built on:
 * matrixDivide.c - Example for illustrating how to use 
 * LAPACK within a C MEX-file.
 *
 * This is a MEX-file for MATLAB.
 * Copyright 2009 The MathWorks, Inc.
 *=======================================================*/
/* $Revision: 1.1.6.2 $ $Date: 2009/05/18 19:50:18 $ */

#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double * pX, * pNumHiddenUnits, * pNumIter, * pkCD; /* pointers to inputs */
    double * pOutput;  /* output arugments */
    mwSignedIndex m,n;     /* matrix dimensions */ 
    int i, j;

      /* Check for proper number of arguments. */
    if ( nrhs != 4)
    {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:RBM:rhs",
            "This function requires 4 inputs.");
    }

    pX = mxGetPr(prhs[0]); /* pointer to first input, X matrix */
    pNumHiddenUnits = mxGetPr(prhs[1]); /* pointer to second input, scalar hidden units */
    pNumIter = mxGetPr(prhs[2]); /* pointer to third input, scalar number of iterations */
    pkCD = mxGetPr(prhs[3]); /* pointer to third input, scalar kCD */

    /* dimensions of input matrix */
    m = (mwSignedIndex)mxGetM(prhs[0]);  
    n = (mwSignedIndex)mxGetN(prhs[0]);

    /* Validate input arguments */
    if (m < 1 && n < 1)
    {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MATLAB:RBM:notamatrix",
            "X must be a matrix.");
    }

    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m, n, mxREAL);
    pOutput = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < m; ++j)
      {
         int index = j * n + i;
         pOutput[index] = pX[i * m + j];
      }
    }
  }
  /* */
```

Comment: sorry have been sick yesterday eve.. caught flu .. will try the above and get back ASAP.. thanks for the hint

Comment: Just checked it very well and yet the input parameters that needs to be given should be of type int , not double ...

Comment: RBM.cpp: In function ‘void mexFunction(int, mxArray**, int, const mxArray**)’:
RBM.cpp:465:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘double*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
RBM.cpp:466:35: error: invalid conversion from ‘double*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]

RBM.cpp:468:27: error: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double’ in assignment
RBM.cpp:525:23: error: conflicting declaration ‘double train_X [6][6]’
RBM.cpp:454:8: error: ‘train_X’ has a previous declaration as ‘double train_X’
RBM.cpp:548:45: error: invalid types ‘double[int]’ for array subscript

Comment: what i would actually like to solve is the following: instead of having the type      double *pX, *pNumHiddenUnits i need to pass them as int

Comment: @JNW you can pass them in the S-Function as an int, but it takes a bit more work.  I would pass as a double, matlabs base numeric type, and then cast them to int's in the S-Function.